# Mongodb count the number of a field with certain condition

Tags: count, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

This is the data I have in the database:

> {
>       "_id" : ObjectId("5bf84d5eb6655873af59ead6"),
>       "game" : 1.0,
>       "action" : {
>           "actionType" : "GameStart",
>           "actionNumber" : 0.0,
>           "Player1" : {
>               "user" : 2.0,
>               "name" : "Kevin"
>           },
>           "Player2" : {
>               "user" : 4.0,
>               "name" : "Sue"
>           }
>       }
>   }

The question is to **report the total number of started games**. I tried this code `db.hw6.count({'action.actionType': "GameStart" })`, and got an error. I have no idea how I did it wrong. can anyone help?

Comment: Failed to execute script.

Error: count failed: {
 "_t" : "OKMongoResponse",
 "ok" : 0,
 "code" : 13,
 "errmsg" : "Cannot execute command ExecuteJavaScript using PrimaryReadonlyMasterKey",
 "$err" : "Cannot execute command ExecuteJavaScript using PrimaryReadonlyMasterKey"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBQuery.prototype.count@src/mongo/shell/query.js:383:11
DBCollection.prototype.count@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1700:12
@(shell):1:1

Comment: The error message suggests you are using Azure CosmosDB rather than MongoDB. Your syntax looks correct for MongoDB, but CosmosDB has a different implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Please use `itcount()` instead of count to solve the error.

It is because you are using Azure CosmosDB rather than MongoDB. `count()` will work for mongodb but in your case you should use `itcount()` which is CosmosDB implementation.

Please refer mongodb documentation. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.itcount/

***********Below error will be resolved after using itcount()*****************

> Error: count failed: { "_t" : "OKMongoResponse", "ok" : 0, "code" : 13, "errmsg" : "Cannot execute command ExecuteJavaScript using PrimaryReadonlyMasterKey", "$err" : "Cannot execute command ExecuteJavaScript using PrimaryReadonlyMasterKey" } : _getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13 DBQuery.prototype.count@src/mongo/shell/query.js:383:11 DBCollection.prototype.count@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1700:12 @(shell):